# галочка не считается

Tags: дефект, знаки

мне показалось, или **"галочка"** (принятие ответа) не считается за **"баллы рейтинга"** (которые необходимы для получения **"знака"**) ?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/942942

и вопрос: если стоит две и более метки, за что будут начислены баллы?

Comment: @Grundy, у меня только на первой странице пять таких ответов. :( я бы хотел предложить изменить механику, мне кажется это поведение не верным.

Comment: Почему неверным? Считаются только числа, наличие или отсутствие галочки число не меняет - все логично.

Comment: я к тому, что есть метка, есть вопрос по этой метке, я даю ответ и мой ответ засчитывают, а он (ответ) не плюсуется мне в метку, поэтому я считаю это не логичным ...